# Is SASL/SSL authentucation supported in kafka low level consumer

Tags: authentication, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am unable to pass any authentication related parameter (for ssl/sasl) in kafka low level consumer. Just wanted to know if the authentication feature is supported in Kafka low level consumer.

- Kafka Server Version: 0.10.1.0
- Kafka Client version: 0.10.2.1/older_versions

Answer (score 0):

SSL and SASL are only available in the Java clients (`org.apache.kafka.clients`).

I'm guessing what you called the "low level" clients are the old Scala clients which are now deprecated and will be remove in one of the next releases. See https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#legacyapis

You should now only use the Java clients which are properly supported, see https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#api